# Flutter run in vscode taking unexpectedly long time

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am using vs code for flutter dev for the first time, while trying to run the app, it's showing me "this is taking an unexpectedly long time".However it builds the application, but takes around 17 mins. Any help??

Comment: You can check which branch of flutter you are using, run from the command line (with verbose option) to check if any errors are being reported.

Comment: Please give some more context, have you added any files to your project, or it might be the speed of your computer. Please provide more context.  Also, try running `flutter doctor` in your cmd/termianl

Comment: what if you run `flutter -v run` from the terminal window? does it take 17 mins too?

Comment: @pskink yes i ran flutter run -v,that's how i got to know how much time is it really taking.

Comment: and was it just compiling your project or it downloaded lots of dependencies?

Comment: @pskink no it was compiling my project,i guess.

Comment: you run it with -v (verbose) so there is no any info about downloading anything?

Comment: @pskink Wait,i'll send the whole log in here

Answer (score 2):

Another issue I've found when building Flutter apps onto a physical Android device specifically, is that ADB may be causing the slow performance.

So running:

```
adb kill-server
```

Then unplugging and replugging the device and then:

```
adb start-server
```

Followed by:

```
flutter run
```

Increased performance

Answer (score 2):

I am a windows user. My pc has a core i5-4200u(2 cores, 4 threads) with only 6GB ram.
If you are trying to run the app in an android emulator or in an android device try this.

Add following lines to the gradle.properties file found in your android folder in your project directory.

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.caching=true
```

Checkout these 3 links for more information

https://www.journaldev.com/12333/increase-gradle-build-speed

https://medium.com/@AthorNZ/how-to-speed-up-your-slow-gradle-builds-5d9a9545f91a

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ll-rkLCtyk

Earlier I had build times like 200s or more. But after enabling these features my build times got significantly lower.
In the first run you won't notice a massive difference. But after that your build times will reduce massively.
After doing all this I got like 40s or less build times.

The build time without the changes mentioned above
[image: The build time without the changes mentioned above]

The build time in the first run after the changes
[image]

The build time in the second run after the changes
[image]

Please note that I have only changed the gradle.properties file to improve build times.

Answer (score 0):

So, I am a Windows PC user with 4GB RAM and i3 processors. I know the thing you're thinking. "Why is it taking so much time?" Believe me, I go through it a lot. Actually, it is not your fault or Flutter's. It is because of the slow PC.

Usually, the 1st run takes time. It has to build packages and stuff. So, it will take time. After the first build, as and when, new dependencies are added, the run time may increase. But after the first build, it runs faster.

Comment: Man i have been working with Flutter on Android Studio for a year now,and it works fine.And my pc has 8GB ram, 1 TB of HDD and powered with Ryzen5.

Comment: Well, then I don't know the problem. But my PC is slow while building Flutter apps.

Comment: In my opinion, 4GBs of RAM will be too little for a PC to function properly it will definitely be your bottleneck, just changing to 8GBs will allow your PC to function properly.